# How to make matplotlib widget in PyQt5 clickable?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am working on GUI where I have tab system with graphs. I want that if a user clicks (or puts cursor) at any point in the graph, it shows the exact x and y values in that point like that:

[image: picture]

I know that in usual matplotlib it is easy to implement; however I do not know how to do that in PyQt5.

My tabs system and canvas look like that:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget,QVBoxLayout,QTabWidget
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mouse_move(event):
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print(x, y)


plt.connect('motion_notify_event', mouse_move)

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=5, dpi=80):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.plot()


    def plot(self):
            x = ['22-02 11:16:15', '22-02 15:31:54', '22-02 15:32:30',
                 '22-02 15:32:45', '22-02 15:33:57', '22-02 15:34:13',
             '22-02 15:34:46']
            y = [1, 4, 3, 4, 8, 9, 2]
            self.figure.tight_layout()
            ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            ax.plot(x, y)


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.top = 255
        self.left = 150
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, 900, 900)
        self.Mainlayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.graphUP = QWidget()
        self.graphUP.layout = QVBoxLayout( self.graphUP)
        self.graphUP.layout.addWidget(Canvas())
        self.tabs.setFixedHeight(800)
        self.tabs.setFixedWidth(800)
        self.tabs.addTab(self.graphUP, "Graph1")
        self.Mainlayout.addWidget(self.tabs)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between "usual matplotlib" and your case. Show the code where you implement it and where it fails for you.

Comment: I have tried to use mouse event, but it didn't work out.

Comment: Check the [event_handling tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html), it's always `figure.canvas.mpl_connect`.

Answer (score 0):

import this module:
import mplcursors as mpl

and add : mpl.cursor(hover=True)

in your def plot() function.

Comment: Please consider providing a complete working example. As is this answer is not clear.