# Matplotlib cross hair cursor in PyQt5

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5, cursor, cross-hair-label

I want to add a cross hair that snaps to data points and be updated on mouse move. I found [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/cursor_demo.html) that works well:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class SnappingCursor:
    """
    A cross hair cursor that snaps to the data point of a line, which is
    closest to the *x* position of the cursor.

    For simplicity, this assumes that *x* values of the data are sorted.
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, line):
        self.ax = ax
        self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        self.x, self.y = line.get_data()
        self._last_index = None
        # text location in axes coords
        self.text = ax.text(0.72, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    def set_cross_hair_visible(self, visible):
        need_redraw = self.vertical_line.get_visible() != visible
        self.vertical_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.horizontal_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.text.set_visible(visible)
        return need_redraw

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            self._last_index = None
            need_redraw = self.set_cross_hair_visible(False)
            if need_redraw:
                self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        else:
            self.set_cross_hair_visible(True)
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            index = min(np.searchsorted(self.y, y), len(self.y) - 1)
            if index == self._last_index:
                return  # still on the same data point. Nothing to do.
            self._last_index = index
            x = self.x[index]
            y = self.y[index]
            # update the line positions
            self.horizontal_line.set_ydata(y)
            self.vertical_line.set_xdata(x)
            self.text.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


y = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
x = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('Snapping cursor')
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
snap_cursor = SnappingCursor(ax, line)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', snap_cursor.on_mouse_move)
plt.show()
```

But I get into trouble when I want to adapt the code with the PyQt5 and show the plot in a GUI. My code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
import sys
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np

class SnappingCursor:
    """
    A cross hair cursor that snaps to the data point of a line, which is
    closest to the *x* position of the cursor.

    For simplicity, this assumes that *x* values of the data are sorted.
    """
    def __init__(self, ax, line):
        self.ax = ax
        self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(color='k', lw=0.8, ls='--')
        self.x, self.y = line.get_data()
        self._last_index = None
        # text location in axes coords
        self.text = ax.text(0.72, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)

    def set_cross_hair_visible(self, visible):
        need_redraw = self.vertical_line.get_visible() != visible
        self.vertical_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.horizontal_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.text.set_visible(visible)
        return need_redraw

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            self._last_index = None
            need_redraw = self.set_cross_hair_visible(False)
            if need_redraw:
                self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        else:
            self.set_cross_hair_visible(True)
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            index = min(np.searchsorted(self.y, y), len(self.y) - 1)
            if index == self._last_index:
                return  # still on the same data point. Nothing to do.
            self._last_index = index
            x = self.x[index]
            y = self.y[index]
            # update the line positions
            self.horizontal_line.set_ydata(y)
            self.vertical_line.set_xdata(x)
            self.text.set_text('x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f' % (x, y))
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        widget=QWidget()
        vbox=QVBoxLayout()
        
        
        plot1 = FigureCanvas(Figure(tight_layout=True, linewidth=3))
        ax = plot1.figure.subplots()
        x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
        y = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * x)
        line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'o')

        snap_cursor = SnappingCursor(ax, line)
        plot1.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', snap_cursor.on_mouse_move)

        vbox.addWidget(plot1)
        widget.setLayout(vbox)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')
        self.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

By running the above code, the data is plotted properly, but the cross hair is only shown in its initial position and does not move by mouse movement. Data values are also not displayed.

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377534/how-to-make-matplotlib-widget-in-pyqt5-clickable) too, but the question is not answered clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

- snap_cursor is a local variable that will be removed when `__init__` finishes executing. You must make him a member of the class.
- The initial code of the tutorial is designed so that the point that information is displayed is the horizontal line that passes through the cursor and intersects the curve. In your initial code it differs from the example and also does not work for your new curve so I restored the logic of the tutorial.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class SnappingCursor:
    """
    A cross hair cursor that snaps to the data point of a line, which is
    closest to the *x* position of the cursor.

    For simplicity, this assumes that *x* values of the data are sorted.
    """

    def __init__(self, ax, line):
        self.ax = ax
        self.horizontal_line = ax.axhline(color="k", lw=0.8, ls="--")
        self.vertical_line = ax.axvline(color="k", lw=0.8, ls="--")
        self.x, self.y = line.get_data()
        self._last_index = None
        # text location in axes coords
        self.text = ax.text(0.72, 0.9, "", transform=ax.transAxes)

    def set_cross_hair_visible(self, visible):
        need_redraw = self.vertical_line.get_visible() != visible
        self.vertical_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.horizontal_line.set_visible(visible)
        self.text.set_visible(visible)
        return need_redraw

    def on_mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            self._last_index = None
            need_redraw = self.set_cross_hair_visible(False)
            if need_redraw:
                self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        else:
            self.set_cross_hair_visible(True)
            x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
            index = min(np.searchsorted(self.x, x), len(self.x) - 1)
            if index == self._last_index:
                return  # still on the same data point. Nothing to do.
            self._last_index = index
            x = self.x[index]
            y = self.y[index]
            # update the line positions
            self.horizontal_line.set_ydata(y)
            self.vertical_line.set_xdata(x)
            self.text.set_text("x=%1.2f, y=%1.2f" % (x, y))
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        widget = QWidget()
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(widget)

        x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)
        y = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * x)

        canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(tight_layout=True, linewidth=3))
        ax = canvas.figure.subplots()
        ax.set_title("Snapping cursor")
        (line,) = ax.plot(x, y, "o")
        self.snap_cursor = SnappingCursor(ax, line)
        canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.snap_cursor.on_mouse_move)

        vbox.addWidget(canvas)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = Window()
w.show()
app.exec()
```